# UITableView with xib(nib) file User-Interface

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I would like to make a UITableView in a xib file so i have an Custom Alert (Simple Alert) and there are Custom Views and they are in xib. So i make a UITableView in the View of the xib file but the Problem is i show the Alert and it´s shows no data. I am new by the xib.files so i have no idea what i make wrong. It´s stranger with the xib.files because when i add a Button in the View and i would print a text on tapped it´s print anything so the Button not reacted. The BookTableView and the subview and view are bound with the files-owner.

Have anyone an idea what i make wrong ? 
Thanks for your Help.

So here was my code for Show the Alert with the custom View:

```
    @IBAction func PlayTapped(sender: AnyObject) {


    let AlertView = TableViewAlertController(nibName: "TableViewAlertController", bundle: nil)

    let AlertTableView = SimpleAlert.Controller(view: AlertView.view, style: .Alert)

    showAlert(AlertTableView)
  }
```

Here the code from the ViewController with the xib.file TableView:

```
import UIKit
import SimpleAlert

class TableViewAlertController: UIViewController {


let items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    subView = UIView()
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: "TableViewAlertController", bundle: nil)
}


@IBOutlet var subView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var BookTableView: UITableView!



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Table Cell clicked")
}
```

}

Thanks for your Help :)

Comment: did you set delegate for the UITableview ?

Comment: yes from the TableView to the files-owner the delegate and datasource.

Comment: so your tableview is display in the alert but no data is displayed in it ? also what are you doing with 'subView' you have created it programatically and via IBOutlet also

Comment: of course the Alert have a Cutomview in there is the tableview he display the tableview but not the data in it so the items. I need subview to init a view to the xib.

Comment: It´s that a problem with the IBOutlet ?? i only know this to connect it with the xib.file.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create the UITableViewCell like this

First register a class for the tableview cell

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

or if you have create xib for tableview cell

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "yourNib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")//same identifier as you have set in 'Reuse identifier' in the cell's xib
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` create cell like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DefaultCell")!
```

Please keep the Cell Identifier name same else if will crash

Comment: I have tried with all 2 func but it´s show no data in the tableview. Can be the Problem the Alert in this code `let AlertTableView = SimpleAlert.Controller(view: AlertView.view, style: .Alert) 
 ` so that it´s call the Controller but not the data in it ??

Comment: I don't have code for SimpleAlert so i can't tell that for sure but you can check for the normal Alert if it's the problem

Comment: Oke but this code must so far oke for UITableView with xib or is something different by a xib.file to a storyboard?

Comment: it looks ok for tableview , you can check by giving the background color to cell if cell background color is displayed or even cell is not display  and for if you are familiar with the storyboard what issue you are facing in making this via storyboard ?

Comment: Oke yes the storyboard is kinder so i tried with the storyboard. Thanks for your Help :)